# Detecting value change using Rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Can we detect if a class member value is getting changed using RxJava?? Say in a class there is a variable var, now can we get notified whenever the value of var changes using RxJava.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
private final BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
private Integer value=0;

public Observable<Integer> getUiElementAsObservable() {
    return subject;
}

public void updateUiElementValue(final Integer valueAdded) {
    synchronized (value) {
        if (valueAdded == 0)
            return;
        value += valueAdded;
        subject.onNext(value);
    }
}
```

and subscribe to it like this:

```
compositeSubscription.add(yourClass.getUiElementAsObservable()
            .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Integer userMessage) {
                    setViews(userMessage,true);
                }
            }));
```

you have to create setter for all of your variables that you want something subscribe to their changes and call onNext if change applied.

****UPDATE****

> When an observer subscribes to a **BehaviorSubject**, it begins by emitting the item most recently emitted by the source Observable

you can see other type of subjects here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

some useful link:
about reactive programming : https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754
and about rxjava : `https://youtu.be/k3D0cWyNno4`

Comment: I am new to RxJava,So if you kindly explain it would be helpful

Answer (score 5):

http://rxmarbles.com/#distinctUntilChanged

### Code

```
Observable.just("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "D")
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(abc -> Log.d("RXJAVA", abc));
```

### Result

```
A
B
A
C
A
D
```

Comment: this function is good for detection but with this code that write above, you have to know the value before subscribe. if you want emit something later you can't use this observable anymore

Comment: actually the problem is with "just", not distinctUntilChanged function.

Comment: It may also be worth it to provide the BiPredicate comparer function as a parameter to distinctUntilChanged() depending on your use case. i.e. in Kotlin, Observable.just("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "D")
    .distinctUntilChanged {string1: String, string2: String -> string1.equals(string2)}
    .subscribe(abc -> Log.d("RXJAVA", abc));
Otherwise it may be using string1 == string2 which many times may not be true